# Shorten list of IF THEN statements from var1 to var20... PHP

Tags: php, list, if-statement, expression

I know this can be shortened and will come easy for someone.  I'd like to use an expression to cut this down to a few lines.  Each of these variables does hold a different value, and may or may not be present.  Thanks for your help!

```
    if ( $lang1 ) {
        echo $lang1 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang2 ) {
        echo $lang2 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang3 ) {
        echo $lang3 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang4 ) {
        echo $lang4 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang5 ) {
        echo $lang5 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang6 ) {
        echo $lang6 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang7 ) {
        echo $lang7 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang8 ) {
        echo $lang8 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang9 ) {
        echo $lang9 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang10 ) {
        echo $lang10 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang11 ) {
        echo $lang11 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang12 ) {
        echo $lang12 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang13 ) {
        echo $lang13 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang14 ) {
        echo $lang14 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang15 ) {
        echo $lang15 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang16 ) {
        echo $lang16 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang17 ) {
        echo $lang17 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang18 ) {
        echo $lang18 ."<br>";
    }       
    if ( $lang19 ) {
        echo $lang19 ."<br>";
    }
    if ( $lang20 ) {
        echo $lang20 ."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: You still have to declare this variables, I wonder if it's done the same way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the values in an array:

```
$langs = array(...);
foreach($langs as $lang)
    echo $lang . '<br>';
```

You can use `array_push()` to add elements to the array.

Comment: Awesome.  One more question: If I wanted to specify one variable to come first, such as "Spanish", and then the rest to be listed in alphabetical order, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it that way, nevertheless, I don't recommend this :

```
for ( $i = 1; $i < 20; $i++ )
    if ( ${"lang$i"} ) // better : if ( !empty(${"lang$i"}) )
        echo ${"lang$i"} . "<br>";
```

which will excatly do what you asked for. But as I said, I don't recommend this, a better solution in others answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Proof: http://codepad.org/qYHZwcbu

```
$my_language_array = array(0 => 'English', 1 => 'French');

foreach($my_language_array as $language)
    if (!empty($language))
        echo $language . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead, like this for each one:

`$lang[10] = 'asdf';`

where `10` is the key, and `asdf` is your value.

Then use a for loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) if ($lang[$i]) echo ($lang[$i] . "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lang1 = 'sss';
$lang2= 'gddd';
    for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{
    $langname ="lang$i"; 
if ($$langname)
{
    echo ($$langname);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

Complementing what Rafe Kettler answered:

```
$langs = array(...);
$desired_lang = '';
foreach($langs as $lang){
    if($lang == $desired_lang)
        echo $lang
}
```

EDIT

Thanks to the downvotes, I just realized that the above code is the dumbest thing i've ever posted, so i'll correct it:

```
if(in_array($desired_lang,$langs))
    echo $langs[$desired_lang]
```

And as Cyclone asked on the comments, if the OP wants more than one language, he could do:

```
$langs = array('lang1', 'lang2','lang3');
$desired_langs = array('lang1','lang2');
foreach($desired_langs as $desired_lang){
    if(in_array($desired_lang, $langs)){
        echo $langs[$desired_lang]
    }
}
```

Downvotes are good, they show you're wrong. :D

Comment: What if more than one lang is desired?